# Build Failed due to Lexical or Preprocessor issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, hockeyapp

I have a project which requires the Hockey framework. I have downloaded this project from the internet. However when I tried to clean + build the project. This message shows up.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ify6f.png)

I don't know why I still got the error. I made sure that the file is there. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you add an entry which define path to your framework's headers folder in `Build Settings` -> `Header Search Paths`?

Comment: Header search path shouldn't be needed.   But the Hockey.framework product does need to be linked by the app target.